# Spring batch file accessing issue?

Tags: java, windows, unix, spring-batch, spring-batch-admin

I am giving the resource value as below in sprin batch writer and readers `file://surfsd11.myhome.net/Ftpfiles/mybox/int/downloaded/myfile.csv`. Spring batch could able to read the file and parse it. 
But i have deployed same application into another server which is running in UNIX environment not able access the same file(path).
What could be the reason? If it is problem with accessing the `surfsd11.myhome.net`. how can i map the same here in UNIX to work with the same.
Please help me on this, i spent lot of time idetifying this.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your issue is path you are trying to access is out of your application, in that case normall you should environment varaibale to read that file path (when you are referring resource outside of your application)

something like this,
your env variable = 'folderpath = surfsd11.myhome.net'

file://#{folderpath}/Ftpfiles/mybox/int/downloaded/myfile.csv

Hope this works.

Regards
Ashok Gudise